# csv parsing & search in java

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV file which looks like this

```
"key,"id.attr.id","id.attr.id1","id.attr.id2","id.attr.id7","id.attr.arry","id.attr.arry1","id.attr.arry2","id.attr.arry5","id.attr.arry4"
// this header goes on for around next 600 field.

"1","0",,,"8",,,"8",,"8"
"2","3",,,"7",,,"7",,"7"
"3","4",,,"8",,,"8",,"8"
"4","5",,,"7",,,"7",,"7"
"5","4",,,"8",,,"8",,"8"
"6","3",,,"7",,,"7",,"7"
"7","4",,,"8",,,"8",,"8"
"8","5",,,"7",,,"7",,"7"
"9","3",,,"8",,,"8",,"8"
"10","6",,,"7",,,"7",,"7"
```

Now I'm trying to search through the content in such a way so that it will return the values 
say for "id.attr.id" it will search for all the corresponding values.

the format of the result will be

```
"key","id.attr.id","id.attr.id7"
    "1","0","8"
    "2","3","7"
    "3","4","8"
    "4","5","7"
    "5","4","8"
    "6","3","7"
    "7","4","8"
    "8","5","7"
    "9","3","8"
    "10","6","7"
```

and also for "id.attr.arry"

Here is the code i'm trying.. but of no use.

```
public void run() {
    String csvFile = "/Users/file.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] id = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            int j=0;
            for ( j:id.size()){
                 if (id[1]=="id.attr.id"+j){
return true;
                     //don't know then how to check                     }
            else     {
                 int i=0;
                 }           }

        }
```

so my question is how to achieve this result?

Comment: Even better: use a CSV parser. Also in Java strings are compared using equals(), not ==.

Comment: `for ( j:id.size()){` is not valid syntax, and please indent your code properly, especially if it's the unclear part.

Comment: Although you have accepted an answer that uses hand-coded Java, I still implore you to use a good quality CSV parser.  CSV files can contain comments, multi-line records, commas embedded inside data, escaped double-quotes and so on (see the [CSV RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)).  Writing code manually for all these cases is not only tough but unnecessary, given that there are good solutions out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of your requirement is you need to build a lookup map between the columns you are looking for and their position in the row. Here's some code that demonstrates how.

```
public List<String[]> selectColumns(String[] csvFile, String... columns) {
    List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    // Split the first row to get the column names.
    String[] columnNames = csvFile[0].split(",");
    // Build a map to get the column number from the name.
    Map<String, Integer> columnNumbers = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
        columnNumbers.put(columnNames[i], i);
    }
    // Put the title columns in.
    String[] colHeaders = new String[columns.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        colHeaders[i] = columns[i];
    }
    rows.add(colHeaders);
    // Walk the rest of the file.
    for (int i = 1; i < csvFile.length; i++) {
        // Get and split the line.
        String[] values = csvFile[i].split(",");
        // Collect the required columns.
        String[] row = new String[columns.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
            // Look up the column number from the header map.
            row[j] = values[columnNumbers.get(columns[j])];
        }
        // Add the row.
        rows.add(row);
    }
    return rows;
}

public void test() {
    // In-line data for demonstration.
    String[] csvFile = new String[]{
        "key,id.attr.id,id.attr.id1,id.attr.id2,id.attr.id7,id.attr.arry,id.attr.arry1,id.attr.arry2,id.attr.arry5,id.attr.arry4",
        "1,0,,,8,,,8,,8",
        "2,3,,,7,,,7,,7",
        "3,4,,,8,,,8,,8",
        "4,5,,,7,,,7,,7",
        "5,4,,,8,,,8,,8",
        "6,3,,,7,,,7,,7",
        "7,4,,,8,,,8,,8",
        "8,5,,,7,,,7,,7",
        "9,3,,,8,,,8,,8",
        "10,6,,,7,,,7,,7"
    };
    List<String[]> selected = selectColumns(csvFile, "key", "id.attr.id", "id.attr.id7");
    for (String[] row : selected) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }

}
```

prints

```
[key, id.attr.id, id.attr.id7]
[1, 0, 8]
[2, 3, 7]
[3, 4, 8]
[4, 5, 7]
[5, 4, 8]
[6, 3, 7]
[7, 4, 8]
[8, 5, 7]
[9, 3, 8]
[10, 6, 7]
```

The suggestions to use a good CSV parser is a very good one - `String.split(",")` is very unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a good quality CSV parser.  I am using [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/), [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net) and [Univocity](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers).

I can wholeheartedly endorse Univocity as its CSV parser is very fast.  Using it, you can [select columns](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers#reading-columns-instead-of-rows).

Comment: but you didn't get my point. how do i compare the field values ?

Comment: With `java.lang.Object#equals(Object)`

Comment: but can u do that i meant to say specially when the values are embedded into the field name. eg id.attr.id7, & id.attr.id6.sch